# Field Boosting Doesn't Work/Effect Lucene.net

Tags: c#, lucene, fuzzy, solr-boost

I'm trying to set boosting on documents fields to make the search results more accurate but as i see it doesn't work

however
here is my code

> Indexing:

```
  private static void _addToLuceneIndex(Datafile Datafile, IndexWriter writer)
    {
        // remove older index entry
        var searchQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("Id", Datafile.article.Id.ToString()));
        writer.DeleteDocuments(searchQuery);

        // add new index entry
        var doc = new Document();
        var id = new Field("Id", Datafile.article.Id.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
        var content = new Field("Content", Datafile.article.Content, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS);
        content.Boost = 4;
        var title = new Field("Title", Datafile.article.Title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
        title.Boost = 6;
        doc.Add(id);
        doc.Add(content);
        doc.Add(title);
        foreach (var item in Datafile.article.Article_Tag)
        {
            var tmpta = new Field("Atid", item.Id.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
            var tagname = new Field("Tagname", item.Tag.name, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
            tagname.Boost = 8;
            doc.Add(tmpta);
            doc.Add(tagname);

        }
        // add lucene fields mapped to db fields

        // add entry to index
        writer.AddDocument(doc);
    }
```

i've used [Lukenet](https://luke.codeplex.com/) to see if the fields boosted however it doesn't and boosting still equal to **1.0**

so i tried to run and test it ,but the result disappoint me anyway

here is my search code:

> searching:

```
 private static IEnumerable<Datafile> _search(string searchQuery, string searchField = "")
    {
        // validation
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchQuery.Replace("*", "").Replace("?", "")))
            return new List<Datafile>();
        var indexReader = IndexReader.Open(Directory, false);
        // set up lucene searcher
        using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader))
        {
            var hits_limit = 1000;
            // search by single field
            var enanalyzer = new SnowballAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30, "English");
            var aranalyzer = new SnowballAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30, "Arabic");
            string[] fields = new string[] { "Title", "Content", "Tagname" };
            // Dictionary<string, float> boosts = new Dictionary<string, float>();
            // boosts.Add("Title", 5);
            // boosts.Add("Content", 3);
            // boosts.Add("Tagname", 7);
            var enparser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, fields, enanalyzer);
            var arparser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, fields, aranalyzer);
            var query = QueryModel(searchQuery, new QueryParser[] { enparser, arparser });
            searcher.SetDefaultFieldSortScoring(true, false);
            TopFieldCollector collector = TopFieldCollector.Create(new Sort(new SortField(null, SortField.SCORE, false), new SortField("Title", SortField.STRING, true), new SortField("Tagname", SortField.STRING, true), new SortField("Content", SortField.STRING, true)),
            hits_limit,
            false,         // fillFields - not needed, we want score and doc only
            true,          // trackDocScores - need doc and score fields
            true,          // trackMaxScore - related to trackDocScores
            false); // should docs be in docId order?
            searcher.Search(query, collector);
            var hits = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;
            var results = new List<Datafile>();
            foreach (var hit in hits)
            {
                var doc = searcher.Doc(hit.Doc);
                var df = _mapLuceneDocumentToData(doc);
                df.score = hit.Score;
                results.Add(df);
            }
            searcher.Dispose();
            return results;
            // search by multiple fields (ordered by RELEVANCE)

        }
    }
```

> QueryModel Method:

```
private static Query QueryModel(string searchQuery, QueryParser[] parsers)
    {

        BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
        searchQuery = "*" + searchQuery + "*";

        foreach (var parser in parsers)
        {
            parser.AllowLeadingWildcard = true;

            var thequery = parser.Parse(searchQuery);

            query.Add(new BooleanClause(thequery, Occur.SHOULD));
        }
        return query;
    }
```

i'm new with lucene.net i love it but i can't get my head around this problem

> PS:

also i want to get a **fuzzy query** as like when the user enter :

**city in russua** to get a result as if he enter: **city in russia**
i tried `FuzzyQuery` Class But it doesn't work anyway ,and is it necessary to use `FuzzyQuery` Class or not to get that result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Since no one answer my question and i have found a solution for this issue i've used a search time query boosting and here is my code:

```
var QParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "Content", analyzer);
QParser.AllowLeadingWildcard = true;
var Query = new QParser.Parse(searchQuery);
Query.Boost = 7.0f;
return Query;
```

you can use `BooleanQuery` if you want to Do an `Or`,`And` search